# Каким образом процедурно расставлять объекты в 2D мире?

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр

Имеется конечный 2D мир, состоящий из чанков, каждый из которых содержит в себе 16x16 тайлов. Размер мира - до 32к x 16к тайлов. Для генерации использую шум перлинга. Мир генерируется не весь сразу, а по мере передвижения игрока. Существуют различные биомы, у каждого из которых имеется некоторый набор тайлов. Например: почва тундры, песок пустыни и так далее.

Пример карты биомов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И необходимо на определённых тайлах расставить объекты (upd: деревья, камни) с какой-то минимальной дистанцией между друг другом, да так, что бы в определённых участках, задаваемых специальной картой плотности (upd: влажность для деревьев, расстояние до гор для камней), эту дистанцию можно было менять. Для этих целей вполне себе может подойти алгоритм Poisson Disk, и я даже его реализовал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, есть проблема. Для работы алгоритма необходимо задать ширину и высоту рабочей области, а я не могу себе позволить генерировать poisson disk для всей карты, потому что она достаточно большая и на генерацию уйдёт непростительно много времени. Мне же необходимо генерировать маленькие кусочки карты, да так, чтобы при повторной генерации одного куска, результат не изменился, и между данным куском и остальными не было заметно швов. Можно ли модифицировать алгоритм Poisson Disk для решения этой задачи, или необходимо искать другой вариант? Если да, то какой?

UPD:
Пример того, чего я хочу добиться
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь точки - это деревья. Как видите, в разных местах плотность деревьев различается. Именно в этом примере плотность зависит лишь от биома. Мне бы хотелось иметь возможность привнести некий элемент случайности, как в примере с Poisson Disk выше. Т. е. иметь в одном биоме поляны с малым кол-вом деревьев, густые леса и так далее.

[Источник](https://www.redblobgames.com/maps/terrain-from-noise/)

В источнике алгоритм крайне неэффективный, и автор сам об этом говорит

Comment: я может быть не въезжаю в какие-то детали, но мне кажется что-то есть лишнее... ваша карта - трехмерный массив 2000x1000x16, карта плотности - 2000x1000x1. Когда на карту устанавливается какой-то объект (в ячейку world[i1][i2][i3] что-то записывается) - в массиве плотности увеличивается на 1 соотв ячейка density[i1][i2]. Можно это развить - при перемещении объекта между тайлами одна ячейка плотности уменьшается а другая увеличивается - и т.д.

Comment: кстати, в игровых движках такие данные удобно хранить в формате текстур

Comment: Мне необходим этот алгоритм для расставления по миру деревьев, камней и всего такого. Для деревьев карта плотности будет равна, например, карте влажности. Для камней - близости к горам. У меня нету массива всего мира, вместо этого есть dictionary с чанками. В каждом чанке хранится 16x16 тайлов. Такой подход позволяет генерировать лишь часть мира возле игрока, что хорошо сказывается на производительности

Comment: но ведь вам нужно сохранять то что вы сгенерировали, потому просто часть массива может оставаться пустой до поры до времени - в массиве просто намного удобнее адресовать. 
а карта лимитов плотности может быть сгенерирована 1 раз во время первого старта игры, например

Comment: Я писал нечто подобное месяца три назад. Сча гляну исходники, попробую описать вам, как примерно я там делал. Скажите только примерный размер "чанка" - участка минимальной площади, которую вы генерируете за раз.

Comment: Карта огромная - 32к * 16к тайлов = 512 миллионов тайлов. Не вижу смысла её полностью генерировать, сомневаюсь что игрок сможет исследовать её всю. К тому же, на генерацию уходит очень много времени. Карта 1к x 1к у меня генерировалась около 5 секунд, соответственно, карта большего размера может генерироваться и минуту, и 5, и 10...

Comment: selya, пока что 16 x 16 блоков (в вопросе, кстати, было написано).

Comment: @grenqa я просто не совсем осознал, что такое тайл в вашем представлении. Я добавил ответ, может будет полезно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я несколько месяцев назад реализовывал нечто подобное для одной своей игрушки. На скриншоте карты видны оранжевые точки - деревья:

[image: карта]

Они расставлены с разной плотностью. Сам алгоритм имеет сложность, соизмеримую с количеством сгенерированных деревьев. Я не знаю, подойдет ли вам такой способ, или нет, так как деревья генерируются для каждого "чанка" отдельно (`per-chunk`).

Небольшое предисловие. Я в своем алгоритме различные структуры генерировал по-разному, но что касается ландшафта и деревьев - они генерировались для каждого чанка отдельно.

У каждого чанка был свой `seed`, по которому этот чанк генерировался. Сид я брал из шума перлина по координатам чанка, к примеру: `seed = getPerlin(chunkX, chunkY)`. Дальше уже используя этот сид я генерировал все структуры на чанке.

А теперь к деревьям. Для начала я выбрал алгоритм, которым можно псевдорандомно расставить деревья. Выбор пал на [`halton sequence`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence). Тут все просто:

```
getHalton(index, base) {
    var result = 0;
    var f = 1 / base;
    var i = index;
    while(i > 0) {
        result = result + f * (i % base);
        i = Math.floor(i / base);
        f = f / base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

`index` - номер в последовательности, `base` - основание. Для того, чтобы расставить точки в двухмерном пространстве, я использовал основания `2` и `3`. Как-то так:

```
var x = getHalton(index, 2) * chunkSize;
var y = getHalton(index, 3) * chunkSize;
```

Здесь `chunkSize` - размер чанка (т.к. значения `getHalton` в интервале `[0, 1]`). Для того, чтобы получать в зависимости от сида различные вариации расстановки деревьев, я вводил переменную `indexShift`. Это просто целое число, сгенерированное по `seed`'у. И мы просто добавляем его к `index`'у.

Для наглядности введем некую функцию `setTree(x, y)`, которая будет устанавливать деревья в той точке чанка, в которой нам нужно. Тогда генерация деревьев будет выглядеть так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < treesCount; ++i) {
    var x = getHalton(i + indexShift, 2) * chunkSize;
    var y = getHalton(i + indexShift, 3) * chunkSize;
    setTree(x, y);
}
```

Хорошо. Теперь у нас есть псевдорандомно расставленные деревья. Но этого же нам не хватит, верно?

И тогда на помощь приходит все тот же шум перлина. Так как я использовал в своем проекте шум, который возвращал значения в диапазоне `[-1, 1]`, а я хотел получить значения между `[0, 1]`, то брал я значение вот так:

```
var value = getPerlin(x * noiseScale, y * noiseScale) * 0.5 + 0.5;
```

Переменная `noiseScale` использовалась для настройки масштаба шума. Хорошо, теперь у нас есть значение в диапазоне `[0; 1]`. Но как это нам поможет? А давайте модифицируем код генерации деревьев вот так!:

```
for (var i = 0; i < treesCount; ++i) {
    var x = getHalton(i + indexShift, 2) * chunkSize;
    var y = getHalton(i + indexShift, 3) * chunkSize;
    var densityInPoint = getPerlin(x * noiseScale, y * noiseScale) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    if (i < treesCount * densityInPoint) setTree(x, y);
}
```

Таким образом, мы отсеиваем некоторую часть деревьев в тех местах, где шум перлина имеет низкие значения.

Итак, что мы имеем: некоторый алгоритм. Результат его работы зависит от трех переменных:

1. `treesCount` - чем больше, тем больше общая плотность деревьев.
2. `noiseScale` - чем больше, тем быстрее меняется плотность на единицу расстояния (тем менее плотность однородна).
3. `densityInPoint` - разные значения дают в целом разный результат.

**P.S.:** кстати, мне показалось, что линейное значение `densityInPoint` дает не очень хороший результат, так что я дополнительно возводил его в квадрат.

**P.P.S.:** на карте видна разная плотность деревьев в разных биомах. Для такого результата я просто задавал разные значения `treesCount` для каждого биома.

**P.P.P.S.:** если у вас деревья выставляются в матрицу, то значения `x` и `y` должны быть целыми. Тогда просто берите целую их часть:

```
setTree(Math.floor(x), Math.floor(y));
```

**P.P.P.P.S.:** я не утверждаю, что такой вариант решения самый лучший и самый правильный. Однако он гораздо быстрее метода, который вы нашли в статье, и для меня он давал приемлимые результаты.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Кажется это то, что мне нужно. Как протестирую - отпишусь